# Is there a way to allow users with "Subscriber" user role to access media library in backend and frontend

Tags: user-roles, user-access

Is there a way to allow users with "Subscriber" user role to access media library in backend and front end with image editing ability? Subscriber can access the media library but unable to edit images with thirdparty plugin. Users under "Subscribers" should be able to access domain.com/wp-admin/upload.php and have ability to edit images both in front end and backend. This is possible with Author user role, but there are many unwanted permission with this user role?

can any one help me please?

Comment: If you did manage this, that doesn't mean the 3rd party plugin will be able to do it, modifications to the 3rd party plugin are almost a certainty. Otherwise you will need to add the capabilities or create a new role. Note that this means any user who registers can upload images to your site as subscriber is the default role, if you have open registration this could become a legal liability ( someone could upload child pornography then report the site and yourself as hosting illicit material )

Comment: The site is well secured with manual checking and all. can you guide me how to add capabilities to allow this?